# Cannot enable microphone for webrtc

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, opera, pubnub

I have downloaded this application [here](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/webrtc/). For some time now that i have added some stuff to it i have been testing it with firefox (from file, not even localhost), everything fine with it (except some cors problems). Though when i tried to test it, even the original version from the site above, i could not make the microphone to work neither on chrome or opera. 
What i mean by that is, in **chrome**, i click on [image] and i allow access (first choice). When the small box is closed it then disallows it by itself again without reloading the page. In **Opera** i just click [image]and after the reload of the page nothing changes Any ideas what is going on here???

EDIT:
After the usage of localhost in order to run files in http most of the cors errors have been gone except from these two: 
[image]

Any ideas why these two persisted?

Answer (score 0):

## WebRTC CORS Errors

You can not load WebRTC using **`file:///`** protocol during your development.  Instead use Simple HTTP such as python like this: **`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`**.  Now you can test your WebRTC app without CORS errors.  Now you can load your WebRTC app using **`http://`** protocol free of CORS Errors.

Also you should save this as a utility for future use by remembering the command via *alias*:

```
alias shs='python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
```

You can also use Apache Web Server as well to solve this.  But it is easier to just paste on your terminal window the simple HTTP Server that comes with Python `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

To run Simple HTTP Server from **Windows, Linux or Mac**, you need to install Python then run the simple HTTP server command: Python2 `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` or Python3 `python -m http.server 8000`.

[image: PubNub WebRTC CORS Errors]

Comment: Wait a bit. When i load the app from the original site (mentioned in the link in my original question), i do not get any cors errors. The errors come up when i load the app from my file:/// , thing that you clarified and i am really thankful for that :) Though the problem remains: Why i can't enable the mic on chrome and opera??

Comment: Except from that, for cors errors, can i use a xamp apache on localhost to get rid of them? (I am not familiar with python..)

Comment: You can give xamp a go and let us know your experience. The microphone issue is outside of PubNub's domain anyways.

Comment: This answer is correct for Chrome and Opera. Firefox allows getUserMedia from file:///

Comment: You can also use Apache Web Server as well to solve this.  But it is easier to just paste on your terminal window the simple HTTP Server that comes with Python **`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`** built into your Mac and Linux boxes by default.

Comment: Please check the edit in my initial question (for what is worth i am using windows on my machine not linux or mac)

Comment: You can do this with windows as well.  I typed basic instructions.